# PDFiumコントロールのサイズを変更したい。

Tags: windows, pdf

PDFiumを利用して、PDFビューワーのWindowsアプリを作りたいと思っているのですが、
PDFiumを配置すると、サイズが変更できず困っております。

```
pdfViewer1.Width  = 500;
pdfViewer1.Height = 300;
```

などとしてもサイズが変わりません。
サイズを変えるにはどうしたら宜しいでしょうか。

Comment: これ [Pdfium.Net SDK](https://pdfium.patagames.com/c-pdf-library/) の関連だったら、サポートしている [フォーラム](https://forum.patagames.com/) で調べるか質問してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: フォーラムがあったんですね。早速確認してみます。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0):

**更新**
[Control.Size Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.size?view=netframework-4.8)プロパティを使うようですね。
そして左上の開始位置は[Control.Location Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.location?view=netframework-4.8)のようです。
それぞれ、第1パラメータが横方向、第2パラメータが縦方向です。

`Form1.Designer.cs`のソースから抜き出したら、こんな風に記述されていました。

```
this.pdfViewer1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1, 1);
this.pdfViewer1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(500, 300);
```

---

**以下は参考に残します**
表示している文書のページならば、おそらく`SizeMode`プロパティを`SizeModes.Zoom`に設定して、`Zoom`プロパティに値(倍率?)を指定することでサイズを変えることが出来るのではないでしょうか？

[PdfViewer Properties](https://pdfium.patagames.com/help/html/Properties_T_Patagames_Pdf_Net_Controls_WinForms_PdfViewer.htm)

> - SizeMode    
>     Control how the PdfViewer will handle pages placement and control sizing
> - Zoom    
>     This property allows you to scale the PDF page. To take effect the SizeMode property should be Zoom

フォーラムの質問例(質問の趣旨は違っていますが)
[Topic: PdfViewer.ScrollToPoint](https://forum.patagames.com/posts/m1342-PdfViewer-ScrollToPoint#post1342)

> ```
>     float x = pdfViewer1.CurrentPage.Width / 2;
>     float y = pdfViewer1.CurrentPage.Height / 2;
>     pdfViewer1.SizeMode = SizeModes.Zoom;
>     pdfViewer1.Zoom = 4;
>     pdfViewer1.ScrollToPoint(0, new PointF(x, y));
> ```

githubのWinFormsサンプル
[Pdf.WinForms/PdfViewer.cs](https://github.com/Patagames/Pdf.WinForms/blob/10e4eccd326650c983c25881b083da983b27b726/PdfViewer.cs)

Comment: 詳細なご回答ありがとうございます！
Zoomは試してみたのですが、
添付画像のようになってしまいます。
PDFファイルを表示している枠を広げたいのですが上手くいかず、
困っております。

Comment: https://scontent-nrt1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/62193189_2485183271514546_1354348774935232512_n.jpg?_nc_cat=101&_nc_ht=scontent-nrt1-1.xx&oh=9b6f505ae83665bf77a31ffc26f3d8eb&oe=5D8AC53B